# Unable to add "))" to the end of each line

Tags: notepad++

Im using Notepad++ and I can't figure this out.

I have numerous lines of text and I need to add `,0x))` at the end of every line.

I tried the following tip

1. Type `$` in the "Find what" field, and `,0x))` in the "Replace with" field.
2. Then hit "Replace All".

But only `,0x` is getting added to the end of each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `)` characters. In the "Replace with" box, instead of `,0x))`, put `,0x\)\)`.

Comment: Note: This is only required if using Regular Expression Mode (which he must be)